# input class="comment-btn" background-color gets out of border

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

input class="comment-btn" background-color gets out of border

> [image: input class="comment-btn" background-color gets out of border]

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. A mere screenshot is not considered an appropriate problem description here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="submit" class="my-btn" value="Send">
```

CSS

```
.my-btn{
  background-color: hotpink;
  border: 1px solid hotpink;
  border-radius: 9px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Please add an explanation for all answers. The site puts answers that have no text description on a queue to review for deletion. People online should be able to come to your answer and get a quick idea of what your code is trying to do rather than having to waste a lot of time reading the question and your answer trying to figure out how your answer may or may not help.